# Custom forms and location of python code

Tags: qgis, python, fields-attributes

I'm working with custom forms for the attribute table of various qgis-object and it works realy well, but I would like to have my forms and their python files separated from the projects. This is not a problem with the ui file but I can't specify a location for the python files. Is this possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python module/file can live anywhere Python can find it. These places can include

1. The current projects folder
2. `.qgis/python`
3. Any path in `sys.path`
4. Paths set in `PYTHONPATH` (normally included in `sys.path`)

If you wanted to include your own serach location you only need to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable before QGIS starts

(*Windows*)

```
SET PYTHONPATH=Z:\MyNetworkPath\yaypythonstuff\;%PYTHONPATH%
```